# How to enable tmpfs in Testcontainers in Go?

Tags: go, testcontainers, tmpfs

To increase the speed of integration tests through Testcontainers in Go, I want to enable tmpfs but it's missing, unlike Java.

In Kotlin, we can say:

```
val container = PostgreSQLContainer(postgresDockerImage)
    .withDatabaseName("dataBaseName")
    .withUsername("username")
    .withPassword("password")
    .withEnv(mapOf("PGDATA" to "/var/lib/postgresql/data"))
    .withTmpFs(mapOf("/var/lib/postgresql/data" to "rw"))
```

EDIT: I solved this by creating a customizer function as follows:

```
func WithTmpfs() testcontainers.CustomizeRequestOption {
    return func(req *testcontainers.GenericContainerRequest) {
        req.Tmpfs = map[string]string{"/var/lib/postgresql/data": "rw"}
        req.Env["PGDATA"] = "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    }
}
```

But I got no performance gain at all.

Comment: Hey Ibrahim Koz, would you like to contribute the `WithTmpfs` to the postgres module?